# Inertia.JS , Laravel closing modal if no validation errors

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

So I have the following method:

```
methods: {
    submit() {    
      this.$inertia.post('/projects', this.form);
      this.openModal = false;
      
    },
},
```

But it closes my modal even if there are validation errors.
I've also tried with

```
this.$inertia.post('/projects', this.form);
      if(!this.$page.props.errors) {
              this.openModal = false;
}
```

Which doesn't close the modal if there are validation errors, but it doesn't close it if the there are no validation errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.$inertia.post` is executed asynchronously, so `this.openModal = false` will most likely finish before you get a response from the server. If you want to see what I mean, put `sleep(10);` somewhere in the controller for the `/projects` route - before the Inertia gets back the response from the server, whatever code you have after `this.$inertia.post` will be executed.

I am assuming your controller redirects back. If your modal is closed by default when the page is loaded, then you can keep the modal open when errors are present with the following:

```
this.$inertia.post(
    this.route("/projects"),
    this.form,
    {
        preserveState: (page) => Object.keys(page.props.errors).length > 0,
    }
);
```

See *Component state* section in the [Inertia docs](https://inertiajs.com/manual-visits) for reference.